# Tensorflow train CNN but accuracy invariable

Tags: tensorflow

First Step
[image: First train step]

Second step
[image: Second step]

Third step
[image: Third step]

Fourth step
[image: Fourth step]

The loss is gradual decline. 
But the accuracy is always around the 50%.

```
# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    # MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')

def conv_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):
    # Tensor input become 4-D: [Batch Size, Height, Width, Channel]

    # Convolution Layer
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    # Apply Dropout
    fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

    # Output, class prediction
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return out

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    # 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
    # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
    # fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
    'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024])),
    # 1024 inputs, 10 outputs (class prediction)
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, num_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
    'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))
}

# Construct model
logits = conv_net(X, weights, biases, keep_prob)
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# Define loss and optimizer
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss_op)


# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

#Saver use to store the model
saver = tf.train.Saver() 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(1, numOfEpoch):
        train_x, val_x, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(Input, Labels, test_size = 0.1)   

        for i in range(0, len(train_x), batch_size):
            trainLoss, _ = sess.run([loss_op, optimizer], feed_dict = {
                X: train_x[i: i+batch_size],
                Y: train_y[i: i+batch_size],
                keep_prob: dropout
            })
            if i % 5 == 0:
                print("The step is in "+ str(i)+ " step")

        valAcc, valLoss = sess.run([accuracy, loss_op], feed_dict={
            X: val_x,
            Y: val_y,
            keep_prob: 1.0})

        print("Step " + str(epoch) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.4f}".format(valLoss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.3f}".format(valAcc))

    print("Optimization Finished!")
    saver.save(sess, "../model.ckpt")
```

Above is the whole code.
The image is [28 * 28 * 1]

The preprocessing for the image is normalization.

And through each epoch, the loss is always down. After sever epoch, the loss is near to 0.72. 
But the accuracy is still around the 50%. When the parameters initialize, the accuracy is already around the 50%. It's never change a lot during the train.

There is also some strange things in prediction.Because the output of prediction is near to 1 and 0, rather than the float value between 1 and 0.

Comment: Is training accuracy calculated across the full dataset? Your network may not be generalizing to the full dataset yet. 4 train steps is not much. You will need to make at least a couple passes through the full dataset before training accuracy starts improving. Also if you can provide some more details (more of the code, the network type, # inputs and # outputs, dataset, etc) that would be helpful.

Comment: Accuracy is calculated across the validation set. The network is train on the full train set. I just put a few step on it. But the accuracy is always around 50% after several steps. It's really strange. And I'll put all the code.

Answer (score 0):

When I change the initializer to xavier initializer.
It seems to be normal.